# Do I need to remove delivered notifications to not surpass the notification limit? - Swift

Tags: swift, unusernotificationcenter

My app schedules 30 notifications every week. I only schedule 30 at a time because there is a limit of 64. So, every week, I update all the notifications by removing them (using `center.removeAllPendingNotificationRequests()`) and refiring them. Do I also need to call `center.removeAllDeliveredNotifications()` to remove the previously delivered notifications so as to not surpass the limit? Or do delivered notifications not count towards the limit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS is limiting the length of the pending list, which means there is nothing to do with the delivered notifications.

But I can only find a [deprecated doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uilocalnotification#overview) and a [radar](http://ileyf.cn.openradar.appspot.com/38065340) that may related to this.